# Does there exist a Unit Matrix for a $m \times n$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, number-theory

By definition, a Unit/Identity matrix (**I**) is a matrix such that,

**I A** = **A I** = **A**

If the matrix A is of dimension **m**$\times$**n**, then unit matrix in **IA** must be of dimension **m**$\times$**m**, while in **A I** should be of dimension **m**$\times$**m**, with element along principal diagonal equal to 1 and rest of the elements equal to zero.

However, the two identity matrices above are not equal, because for two matrices to be equal, their respective $(i,j)$th element should be equal.

So could you please explain why don't we say there is no unit matrix for such cases, instead of using two different matrices?

Because there is not one matrix (for **m**$\times$**n** matrix) such that **I A** = **A I** = **A**. Basically there are two different matrices.

Comment: Like you say, if both equalities hold, then $I$ has dimension $m \times m$ but also dimension $n \times n$, and thus $m = n$.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the definition of identity matrix is not quite the one you gave. The simplest thing is to just define the $n\times n$ identity matrix $I_n$ as the $n\times n$ matrix with $1$ on the diagonal and $0$ elsewhere.

This matrix (or set of matrices, one for each $n$) has various properties. For example, $I_n B=B I_n=B$ for every $n \times n$ matrix $B$ (and *this* could be taken as a definition, if one prefers, since it uniquely determines $I_n$).

Now, *another* property is that for every $m \times n$ matrix $A$, we have $I_m A = A I_n = A$. But this property of course involves two different $I_m$ and $I_n$ if $m \neq n$. What's the big deal with this? The vector space of $m \times n$ matrices doesn't form an algebra if $m \neq n$ (you can't multiply them), so thinking about the general definition of an identity element of an algebra is pointless in that context.

Comment: Concept of identity matrix comes as an extension of identity (1) in algebra.
So for a matrix to qualify as identity matrix, **AI** = **IA** = **A** should be satisfied. From that we get the definition that identity matrix (for square matrix) should have all diagonal elements equal to 1.
Anyway it's not possible to do so for m x n matrix so we have made some changes to how we define an identity element in matrix algebra.
I was reading "Mathematical methods for Physicists" and it was mentioned that instead we should take two different matrices as identity matrix. So I wanted some clarification.